# Convert .PNG image to .JPEG after upload

Tags: php

```
    $file_extension= explode('.', $file_name); 
    $file_extn= strtolower(end($file_extension));  
    $old_file_path = $user_data['profile_pic'];

      function change_profile_image($user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn, $old_file_path){
            $file_path = 'core/images/profile/'.  substr(md5(time()), 0, 20) . '.' . $file_extn;
            move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
            if(file_exists($old_file_path) === true){unlink($old_file_path);}
            mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `profile_pic` = '". mysql_real_escape_string($file_path) ."' WHERE `user_id` = " . (int)$user_id);

            if($file_extn == 'png'){
            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($old_file_path);
            $new_width = $width;
            $new_height = $height;
            $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($old_file_path);

            imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
            imagejpeg($image_p, $file_path);
if(file_exists($old_file_path) === true){unlink($old_file_path);}           
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `profile_pic` = '". mysql_real_escape_string($file_path) ."' WHERE `user_id` = " . (int)$user_id);
            }

            if($file_extn == 'jpg' || $file_extn == 'jpeg'){
            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file_path);
            $new_width = $width;
            $new_height = $height;
            $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_path);

            imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
            imagejpeg($image_p, $file_path);
if(file_exists($old_file_path) === true){unlink($old_file_path);}           
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `profile_pic` = '". mysql_real_escape_string($file_path) ."' WHERE `user_id` = " . (int)$user_id);
            }
        }
```

The image is uploading but the problem is it is not converting the image after the upload. What is the problem? I believe the if statements aren't working.

Comment: Should you use a case insensitive string compare (or a "real" string compare instead of `==`?

Comment: Never mind - I just noticed the `strtolower` function near the top...

Comment: Yup, its annoying that this isn't working

Comment: What have you tried for debug? I would litter the code with `echo` to see whether lines are executed and what the value of variables is

Comment: Sometimes the issue with these things is permissions. Can you write a simple file to the location where you want to create your converted files? It's a necessary, but not sufficient condition for this to work. After that, I would try to just save the renamed file - no other conversions etc; and finally, I would add the conditionals, conversions, etc. Eventually things will stop working, and there's your smoking gun...

Comment: No, I do have permissions to write on the folder. I don't know why it is not executing. I don't see anything wrong with it. Its soo annoying bro, gah...

Comment: Just to confirm: you have successfully written files to these locations with php (not exactly the same answer as "I have permissions"). When you add an `echo 'some useful info'` after every line, where do things break?

Comment: Yes, it writes onto the folder no problem, but it returns with a black image. I have posted a more detailed question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929278/

Answer (score 0):

```
...
move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
if(file_exists($old_file_path) === true){unlink($old_file_path);}
...
if($file_extn == 'png'){
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($old_file_path);
...
```

I believe that, since you're deleting `$old_file_path` before using `getimagesize($old_file_path)` it fails, so `imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);` has nothing to work on.

Try commenting the first file deletion, right after `move_uploaded_file`. Pretty sure that's the problem...

Comment: Nope, that did not fix the problem.